# If $p_1 = 0.3$ and $p_2 = 0.4$, what is the probability that it will take Jay more than 12 hours to be successful on both jobs?

Tags: probability-distributions, self-learning

Jay has two jobs to do, one after the other. Each attempt at job $i$ takes one hour and is successful with probability $p_i$. If $p_1 = 0.3$ and $p_2 = 0.4$, what is the probability that it will take Jay more than 12 hours to be successful on both jobs?

I don't know how to start on this question, can someone give me some hints to help me start off? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want a hint, then note that the probability of p1 not happening is .7 and probability of p2 not happening is .6. All you need to do is find all the ways he can fail a total of 12 times.

Comment: @mathguy I think he does not need to fail 12 times !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a clear answer we need the strategy that Jay uses in choosing a job to try.  Let's say he tries job $1$ until he succeeds, then tries job $2$.  The chance he never gets job $1$ done is $0.7^{12}$.  The chance he fails job $1$ the first $i$ times, succeeds on try $i+1$ and never gets job $2$ is $0.7^i\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.6^{11-i}$  The total chance of failure is then $$0.7^{12}+\sum_{i=0}^{11}0.7^i\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.6^{11-i}$$

Comment: Well it is not the case with most of us, we don't try a question 12  times before we succeed , or even i think we shouldn't .lol

Answer (score 1):

Given the age of this I sort of doubt that this will help much, but I'm pretty certain magicjake is right on this one, though Ross's answer only differs by ~0.008 .

For sums of independent random variables we can compute their probabilities like so:

Given two independent random variables X & Y, the $P(X + Y \leq k)$ is (in the discrete case):

$$P(X+Y <= k) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1-i}f_{x}(i)f_{y}(j)$$

Recalling now that for the geometric distribution $P(X = k) = q^{k - 1} \cdot p$ where $p$ is the probability of success on a trial and $q = 1 - p$.

So we have the solution:

Let X be the time it takes to complete job 1, Y be the time it takes to complete job 2.  We're looking for $P(X + Y > 12)$ which is equivalent to $1 - P(X + Y \leq 12)$

$$P(X + Y <= 12) = \sum_{i = 1}^{11}\sum_{j=1}^{11-i}(0.7)^{i-1} \cdot (0.3) \cdot (0.6)^{j-1} \cdot (0.4) \approx 0.96$$

$$P(X + Y > 12) = 1 - P(X + Y \leq 12) = 1 - 0.96 = 0.04$$
$$Or \ 4\%$$

My solution differs from magicjake in the placement of $i-1$ versus $j-1$, but a quick calculator jam reveals that the answers are identical.

**PLEASE NOTE: I'm only a student and it's possible that Ross's equation is actually the accurate one.  Mine is extrapolated from the continuous case in my textbook (since it doesn't cover the discrete case for some odd reason.)**

Answer (score 0):

Let's say he attempted  1st job $a$ times and second job $b$ times unsuccessfully. So,$a+b=11$ will serve our purpose that he'll have to attempt both jobs at least once again to successfully complete the job, and thus complete jobs in more than 12 hours.

But I have not got any way to directly inculcate all cases $(a,b)$.I think we have to add for each case one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Let m be number of trials for the Job1, and n be the number of trials for Job2.

The question asks $P( m+n >12 ) = 1 - P (m+n<=12) = $
$$
1 - \sum_{n=1}^{11} \sum_{m=1}^{11-n}(0.7)^{m-1}(0.3)^{1}(0.6)^{n-1}(0.4)^{1}
$$

To visualize it let call $1$ for success and $0$ for failure..

so our sample space can look like

$11------------$ where $n=1,m=1$ (Trial$1$ j$1$ successful, trial$1$ job$2$ successful)

$011-----------$ where $n=1, m=2$ (Trial$1$ $j1$ failed, trial$2$ $j1$ successful, trial$1$ job$2$ successful)

and so on

$000000000011------$ where $n=1, m=11$

$101-----------$ where $n=2,m=1$

$0101----------$ where $n=2,m=2$

and so on

$00000000000101$ where $n=10,m=2$

the final option will be which $n=11$ and $m=1$,

$100000000000001 ... $